# Symfony2: How can I authenticate users using a non default Entity Manager?

Tags: symfony, entitymanager

I need that when users log in, they are authenticated using a second database whose connection in not the default one. I have read many posts about creating user providers which extends UserProviderInterface but none of them worked.

What I have done til now:

1. I have a custom user class (MyCustomUser) which extends the FOSUser class.
2. I have defined two connections and two entity managers in my config.yml file.
3. I have defined a provider of my custom user class in security.yml:

   providers:

   ```
     chain_provider:
         chain:
             providers: [in_memory, fos_userbundle, myusers]
     ...

     myusers:
         entity: { class: myproject\myBundle\Entity\MyCustomUser}
   ```

The problem is that when I try to log in using the credentials (username/password) of MyCustomUser instances, Symfony tries to validate this data against the default connection, where MyCustomUser table doesn't exist. In other words, it's trying to load data from the default connection and an error like "table default_connection.MyCustomUser does not exist".

What steps should I follow to load the entity manager I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is my answer already sufficient or do you need more information on how to inject the non-default connection into your provider?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject your non-default entity manager into your custom user-provider which implements [UserProviderInterface](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.html).

Then use it in the `loadUserByUsername($username)` method.

Comment: Still not working. I created a UserRepository class which extends EntityRepository and implements UserProviderInterface, and defined loadUserByUsername($username) method as you told me, which calls $this->getEntityManager('non-default-entity-manager'), as well as refreshUser(UserInterface $user) and supportsClass($class) methods. After that, I added the following annotation to MyCustomUser class: @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="myproject\myBundle\Entity\UserRepository"). The error I get now is "The Doctrine repository "Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository" must implement UserProviderInterface."

Comment: I managed to solve that problem, and my users are authenticated against the non-default connection. The problem now is that, after successful login, Symfony tries to update the field last_login in a table named myCustomUser in the default database, and since that table doesn't exist, it tries to executo an INSERT INTO of the myCustomUser, which fails. How can I use the default database to perform the user update? I am using Symfony 2.3 and the lines of code that fail are, in file \vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager.php, the updateUser() function.